# Ethereum Alarm Clock

Tags: contract-development, ropsten, scheduling

I am trying to test a smart contract which uses the [Ethereum Alarm Clock](http://www.ethereum-alarm-clock.com/) . They have mentioned a [contract address](http://blog.ethereum-alarm-clock.com/blog/2016/10/4/available-on-the-testnet) for the testnet. But that is old and it is not available for any of the new testnets. I am running my contract on ropsten network.

I saw a couple of solutions which suggested to deploy the contract from source separately and use that for development purpose. Also there were a lot of issues posted. Just wondering if there is a better workaround or any previously deployed Scheduler Contract on ropsten that I can use for development purpose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, I was not able to find a SchedularAPI contract in testnet. But found an alternative solution where I was able to use oraclize to do pretty much the same thing. If you are not using oraclize in your contract then you can use a empty oraclize query with a time delay and a callback.

Answer (score 0):

Current [Ethereum Alarm Clock](https://www.ethereum-alarm-clock.com) Ropsten testnet scheduler addresses are:

```
{
    "blockScheduler":"0x190854329c1edef8cfc6325fa43f1710b3f73f57",  
    "timestampScheduler":"0xaba1c9637f79ae219a6aa0e93b47d5a6b91eb7de"
}
```

They can be found here: https://github.com/ethereum-alarm-clock/eac.js-lib/blob/master/lib/assets/ropsten.json.